# Is there a way for a url open in a new window

Tags: html

Is there anything that I can suffix to a url so that it opens in new browser window instead of redirects?

I saw a few suggestions on the web, but nothing actually works.

for example:
http://www.zzz.com\?tp=win95 target=_blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `target="_blank"` attribute on your link

For example :

```
<a href="http://www.zzz.com\?tp=win95" target="_blank"/>
```

Comment: So you mean I cannot type a url into a browser address box and have it open into a new browser window?

Comment: Use `CTRL+T` shortcut on your browser to open a new tab and then type your url ?

Comment: I was hoping for something simple because my link on my sharepoint 2010 list does not open into a new browser window and the suggestions for that were not working out for me.

Comment: You can wheel-click a link, it will open the page in a new tab.

Comment: Opens in a new tab of the same browser window but does not open a new/separate window.

Answer (score 0):

No, that has to be specified by the link itself:

```
<a href="http://www.zzz.com\?tp=win95" target="_blank"/>
```

or by JavaScript:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace);
```

Here's a link to the JS method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

You leave the target as blank.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Comment: [Please avoid recommending w3schools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Sorry, didn't know i wasn't supposed to. Edited

Comment: It's not a rule or anything, but many developers believe that they're not a very good resource, as explained in the link I posted above.

Comment: @Chris I am checking it out. And i am finding myself agreeing. Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for a better resource, the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is very good.

Comment: @Chris Cheers! Checking it out!